# No records in public database using CloudKit and Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit

My goal is to provide a global/public database to all users using CloudKit and Core Data but only I can add or change it. Therefore I think that a public database is the right choice for me. Here is my problem: With the private database there are no problems, all entries exist and are correct. But when I changed the `datascope` to `public`, it does not work anymore.

For testing I used this project https://github.com/dannysantoso/Medium-Article-CoreData-and-CloudKit and changed the persistentContainer to

```
 lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "LocalStorageModel")
        
        
        guard let description = container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first else {
            fatalError("### \(#function): Failed to retrieve a persistent store description")
        }
      
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentHistoryTrackingKey)
        description.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSPersistentStoreRemoteChangeNotificationPostOptionKey)
        description.cloudKitContainerOptions?.databaseScope = .public
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError?{
                //Error Condition
            }
        })
        
        
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        container.viewContext.mergePolicy = NSMergeByPropertyObjectTrumpMergePolicy

        do {
            try container.initializeCloudKitSchema(options: NSPersistentCloudKitContainerSchemaInitializationOptions())
        } catch {
            print("Cloud schema error found: \(error)")
        }
        
        return container
    }()
```

I also add two indices to Record Types in the iCloud dashboard, namely recordName and modifiedTimestamp. [image]
I do not know why the added data will not sync or be uploaded to the public database. As mentioned with private database there are no problems.

Comment: There are some settings in the dashboard.  Whether or not the user can read data depends on how you adjust them.

Comment: @ElTomato Where I do find this point in the dashboard ? I do not see them. But I thought a public database should always be accessible to everyone.

Comment: Did you meanwhile find out something here?

Comment: @Maschina At that time it does not work with the Xcode Simulator. You have to use a device. Nowadays it should work fine! I have no problems with CloudKit on the simulators.